# Server 2012, SSL (let's encrypt), nodejs app, redirect port

Tags: node.js, windows, ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

There are nay way for next

1. (SRV) Windows Server 2012 with public ip 11.22.33.44
2. (SRV) Windows Server 2012 has OpenVPN server
3. (SRV) Windows Server 2012 has IIS site with https (let's encrypt) https://some-site.com
4. (PC) Windows 10 with OpenVPN client ip 192.168.15.6
5. (PC) on Windows 10 runned node app on port 8888
6. I can open http://192.168.15.6:8888 on SRV

Can I redirect all between https://some-site.com <-> http://192.168.15.6:8888?

Why?

1. There are external app which can connect only to https://some-site.com
2. There are C# app which work on https://some-site.com
3. I`m Developer, want rewrite C# app to nodejs app on PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Url-rewrite allow redirect https traffic from public IIS to local PC by OpenVPN channel.